# Are there any incremental (interactive) shell utils? I.e. "online" sort, wc etc

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, interactive

Are there there versions (drop-in replacements) of the standard shell utils that displays (partial) results updated on-the-fly (perhaps to stderr)?

Say I want to do this:

```sh
du ~/* -s | sort -rn | head
```

At first absolutely nothing happens, before `du` is done. I would however like to see partial results, i.e. I want `sort` to show the data it has already seen. This way I can quickly see if something is wrong with the output and correct it. Like when running grep.

Same thing with this:

```sh
du ~/* -s | wc
```

I would like it to update on the fly.

Here is an ugly work-around showing kinda what I want. (But preferably it shouldn't unnecessarily consume the whole screen, like with `du` below.)

```sh
du ~/* -s > /tmp/duout | watch -n .1 sort -rn /tmp/duout

du ~/* -s > /tmp/duout | watch -n .1 wc /tmp/duout
```

However, I'd much prefer it if I could just do like:

```sh
du ~/* -s | isort -rn
```

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of shell utilities that display active results. A good example would be the `top` program.

The trouble is, these kind of tools do NOT lend themselves to the usual linux methodology of input and output. `Sort` is meant to take an input stream, sort it, and output it. You can then take that output and do something else with it. If it output incremental versions, it would be useless for further processing.

If you have specific needs to see partial data, you will have to hack them together yourself. It's diametrically opposed to the normal work flow and a massive waste of computing resources. Such excessive are left up to the reader :)

If you have another specific utility and wonder if there would be an alternative display system, feel free to ask. As for the ones you mention, particularly `sort`, they don't exist. A live display of output in `sort` would slow results down by several orders of magnitude and nobody wants to watch output at the cost of waiting ten or a hundred or a thousand times longer for the final result.

Comment: How often is `sort` the slowest step in a pipeline anyway? I was hoping for something using some online sorting algorithm, possibly showing partial results on stderr so stdout is still useful in the pipeline. Actually, it'd just have to keep track of the (e.g.) 10 biggest/smallest. Hmm... Could an online sort perhaps be faster in some cases? E.g. if input is coming in slowly there wouldn't need to be a long pause after the last byte is received.

Comment: Your first question is irrelevant. The correct question would be, "How often does sort take up any time at all?" All the little things add up you know. Your last question is quite interesting. It's possible that it could be faster to do an incremental sort in some cases. Not more efficient, but less time on the wall clock. However your case sounds very specific. Maybe you should write something up!

Answer (score 1):

You can insert `tee /dev/tty` into a pipe sequence to print intermediate results. `tee` duplicates stdin, sending output both to stdout and to any files specified on the command-line. You could use this trick to view du's output while simultaneously passing it to sort:

```bsh
du ~/* -s | tee /dev/tty | sort -rn | head
```

The intermediate output will collide with sort's output. You could work around this with various shell tricks; for example, by sending sort's output to a pager:

```bsh
du ~/* -s | tee /dev/tty | sort -rn | less
```

Comment: or sending sort output to a file for review later. i.e. `du ~/* -s | tee /dev/tty | sort -rn > duInfo.txt`. Thanks for sharing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the utils, but the shell itself. You need a different shell that will  start each process in a pipe chain at the same time. The utilities all stream input just fine. Run a recursive grep to prove that to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal case of sorting data, you have to read all the data before you can start to print the value for line 1 of data, right? And as you mention, same with du -s (which means summary, it is sorting and collating data too). Take out the `-s` and you get unsummarized output right away.

So you're always going to have to wait for those sorts of things. The one thing you can do with your first example is to add a `tee` into the data stream

```
du ~/* -s | tee /dev/tty | sort -rn | head
```

or even

```
du ~/* -s | tee /dev/tty8 | sort -rn | tee /dev/tty12 | head
```

where tty8 and tty12 are separate terminal windows, and you have found the correct ttyN to substitute by using `tty` in the shell window.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.